# Change columns to row in SQL table (Salesforce CRM)

Tags: sql, database, pivot, salesforce

I'm using salesforce analytics studio and from my dataset I produce this table:

| REGION_NAME | PROFIT | CA | COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FR | 10 | 20 | 10 |
| UK | 20 | 40 | 20 |

from this query:

```
SELECT
    REGION_NAME
    ,sum(CA) as CA
    ,sum(COSTS) as COST
    ,(sum(CA) - sum(_COSTS)) as PROFIT
FROM "DATASET_NAME" 
GROUP BY REGION_NAME
```

However I'm trying to display my value as follows:

| Type | FR | UK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROFIT | 10 | 20 |
| CA | 20 | 40 |
| COST | 10 | 20 |

How should I update my query ? I suppose I could use PIVOT function but I don't how to apply it in this case.

To create a sample of my dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE DATASET_NAME (
    CA INT,
    COST INT,
    REGION_NAME VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO DATASET_NAME (CA, COST, REGION_NAME)
VALUES 
    (10, 5, 'FR'),
    (10, 5, 'FR'),
    (40, 20,'UK');
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question and include my answer in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need an *unpivot* here, followed by a pivot:

```sql
SELECT
    TYPE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN REGION_NAME = 'FR' THEN VAL END) AS FR,
    MAX(CASE WHEN REGION_NAME = 'UK' THEN VAL END) AS UK
FROM (
    SELECT 'PROFIT' AS TYPE, REGION_NAME, PROFIT AS VAL FROM DATASET_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CA', REGION_NAME, CA FROM DATASET_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'COST', REGION_NAME, COST FROM DATASET_NAME
) t
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

Comment: Thank for tour quick answer ! Why the first field after the select are between quote ? (like SELECT 'PROFIT')

Comment: That is part of the unpivot operation, because we want to turn columns (e.g. `PROFIT`) into rows.  The single quotes just denotes `'PROFIT'` as being a string literal.

Comment: I understand, so to apply this to my case I must replace profit, ca and cost by their sum (like: SELECT 'CA', REGION_NAME, sum(CA) FROM DATASET_NAME)? Because when I doing it like this I have the following error: `SELECT Error: Aggregate and non-Aggregate fields cannot be used at the same time.`

Comment: Your current query looks to be going in the wrong direction.  You need an unpivot operation--somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean I should apply an unpivot operation, there wasn't one in your answer ? I edit my question to show my current query

Comment: In my answer, the subquery aliased as `t` is doing an unpivot.

Comment: Then I don't understand your previous suggestion. I juste use your answer and replace CA by sum(CA), COST by sum(COST), and PROFIT by ((sum(..)-sum(..))